# Как высчитывать и ставить высоту window в js

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть скрипт, он высчитывает высоту и ставит ее блоку, но если окно поменять без перезагрузки, высота остается та же, как сделать чтобы высота автоматически, без перезагрузки высчитывала высоту window и изменяла высоту блока

```
 var bh = $(window).height();
 $('.home-topp').css('height', bh+'px');
```

Answer (score 3):

Пора уже перестать возиться с пикселями и скриптов и сделать просто

```
.home-topp { height: 100vh; }
```

[Поддерживается в](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) IE9+, FF 19+, Chrome 20+, Safari 6+, Opera 15+ (жаль, что 12 не умеет).

Comment: Резонно, до сих пор пугаюсь 100vh из-за различий 100vw и 100% xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev, мне и 100% нравится, если нормально использовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
function blockSize(){
  var bh = $(window).height();
  $('.home-topp').css('height', bh+'px');
};
$(window).on('load resize',blockSize);
```

При загрузке страницы, и при изменении размера, будет выполнятся функция blockSize, в которой пропишите то что нужно делать :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  $('.home-topp').height($(this).height());
});
```

```css
.home-topp { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-topp"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет об высоте на весь экран то есть ед. изм. `vh`;

```css
body {
background: #da3;
}
.home-topp { 
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-topp"></div>
```